# How to upload a file to cPanel File Manager in VB.NET application?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, cpanel, whm

I need users to be able to upload a file to a table in my SQL database; the table would contain a column for the file URL/name/whatever is the easiest method.

I have a server database and a VB.NET application which uses SELECT and INSERT SQL commands to send and retrieve data. Currently my VB.NET application can register, login, and verify (through email) user accounts (this information is stored in a 'user' table). However, I need users to be able to upload files to another table ('userFiles') in my database. I am using phpMyAdmin to modify my database.

This is [some code I found](https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/upload_blocking.asp) which uses [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com) which I attempted:

```
Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim upload As New Chilkat.Upload
    '  Specify the page (ASP, ASP.NET, Perl, Python, Ruby, CGI, etc)
    '  that will receive and process the HTTP Upload.
    upload.Hostname = "example.com"
    upload.Path = "/ReceiveUpload.aspx"

    '  Add one or more files to be uploaded.
    upload.AddFileReference("file1", "path/to/file")

    '  Do the upload.  The method returns when the upload
    '  is completed.
    '  This component also includes asynchronous upload capability,
    '  which is demonstrated in another example.
    Dim success As Boolean = upload.BlockingUpload()
    If (success <> True) Then
        Console.WriteLine(upload.LastErrorText)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Files uploaded!")
    End If
End Sub
```

The example page had a [link](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_534.asp) which lead to the whereabouts of the "ReceiveUpload.aspx" file, along with a "ReceiveUpload.aspx.cs" file, both which (presumably) would be on my server for my application to run. All unsuccessful.

This is what I **expect** to happen:

- User selects file on their computer and presses upload
- VB.NET application sends the file to the server
- Server receives the file and stores it inside a folder called 'userFiles'
- Server sends back a direct link to download that file to the application

This is what ***actually*** happens (upon running the aforementioned code):

- VB.NET application outputs 'Files uploaded!', as if the upload was successful
- No file is found on my server
- No way to retrieve a direct link (URL or other) to the uploaded file

I would greatly appreciate any help. I have searched for a long time and cannot find anything which provides a solution. I am (clearly) new to this.

Comment: if you want to insert the file into a row in your database, then you don't upload it, you pass the data from the file (usually converted to a byte array) into a blob column in the database, via a parameter in your INSERT query.

Comment: But if you wanted to put the file onto the filesystem instead (it's usually more efficient to store a file on the filesystem, and in the database just store the path to the file), then most cPanel hosted accounts will allow FTP, so you should write code which will upload the code via FTP.

Comment: N.B. Trying to upload it via HTTP won't be easy because you'd have to try and sign in to the cPanel GUI interface via your VB code, get the session cookie and then somehow navigate to the upload page and send a request as if you were a human user. Massive PITA, if it's even realistically possible at all. Putting a special "upload" script on the server itself to receive your request is possible, but a) could be a security risk, b) cPanel accounts usually support PHP/Perl, rather than ASP.NET, so you'd have to write the receiving code in one of those languages, c) is unnecessary because of FTP